# Spring security with dynamic privilege checking

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

```
<div xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <span sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(${p})">
<button>Save</button>
</span>
</div>
```

I have this code for checking the privilege of accessing the save button.

model.addAttribute("p", p); added at the controller with p as comma separated privileges.  So how do I check user has any of the given roles.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using **[Preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing)** feature. You can do it as follows:

```
<div xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <span sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(__${p}__)">
<button>Save</button>
</span>
</div>
```

Note the use of double underscore beginning and end characters in which thymeleaf evaluates this expression before anything else.